# Exception: java class boolean return inside of a system print statement when called

Tags: java

my code is just some classes, my most recent one is the admitted class and it is causing problems when I try to print.
Heres the code -

**Customerrr.java**

```
class Customerrr {
    String name;
    int age;
    float money;

    public Customerrr(String initName, int initAge) {
        name = initName;
        age = initAge;
    }

    public Customerrr(String initName, int initAge, float initMoney) {
        name = initName;
        age = initAge;
        money = initMoney;
    }

    public Customerrr() {
    }

    public double computeFee() {
        //adult fee $12.75 anyone 18+
        //3 and under no fee
        //65 or oldr %50
        //4 to 17 $8.50
        double result;

        if (age < 3) {
            result = 0.0;
        }

        else if (age < 17){
            result = 8.50;
        }
        else if (age < 64) {
            result = 12.75;
        }
        else {
            result = 12.75/2;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public boolean spend(float amount) {
        boolean checker;
        if (amount > money) {
            amount = (float) (amount - computeFee());

            checker = true;
        }
        else {
            amount = amount;
            checker = false;
        }
        return checker;
    }

    public boolean hasMoreMoneyThan(Customerrr c){
        boolean result;
        if (money > c.money) {
            result = true;
        }
        else {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public boolean payAdmission() {
        System.out.println(name + " has paid $" + computeFee() + " for admission");
        boolean result;
        if (spend(money)) {
            result = true;
        }
        else {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean admitted () {
        boolean result;
        if (payAdmission()) {
            result = true;
        }
        else {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here my class with main method, that instantiate `Customer` and calls methods on it. Everytime I try to execute the main method I get an exception : `java class boolean return inside of a system print statement when called`

**AddingMethods.java**

```
public class AddingMethods {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Customerrr c1, c2, c3, c4;
        c1 = new Customerrr("Bob", 17, 100);
        c2 = new Customerrr("Dottie", 3, 10);
        c3 = new Customerrr("Jane", 24, 40);
        c4 = new Customerrr("Sam", 72, 5);

        System.out.println(" Bob has been admitted ... " + c1.admitted);
        System.out.println(" Dottie has been admitted ... " + c2.admitted);
        System.out.println(" Jane has been admitted ... " + c3.admitted);
        System.out.println(" Sam has been admitted ... " + c4.admitted);
        c1.payAdmission();
        System.out.println("Bob has been admitted ... " + c1.admitted);
        c2.payAdmission();
        System.out.println("Dottie has been admitted ... " + c2.admitted);
        c3.payAdmission();
        System.out.println("Jane has been admitted ... " + c3.admitted);
        c4.payAdmission();
        System.out.println("Sam has been admitted ... " + c4.admitted);
        System.out.println(" Bob has $" + c1.money);
        System.out.println(" Dottie has $" + c2.money);
        System.out.println(" Jane has $" + c3.money);
        System.out.println(" Sam has $" + c4.money);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the parenthesis when you call the method **admitted** in Customer, like this:

```
        System.out.println(" Bob has been admitted ... " + c1.admitted());
        System.out.println(" Dottie has been admitted ... " + c2.admitted());
        System.out.println(" Jane has been admitted ... " + c3.admitted());
        System.out.println(" Sam has been admitted ... " + c4.admitted());
        c1.payAdmission();
        System.out.println("Bob has been admitted ... " + c1.admitted());
        c2.payAdmission();
        System.out.println("Dottie has been admitted ... " + c2.admitted());
        c3.payAdmission();
        System.out.println("Jane has been admitted ... " + c3.admitted());
        c4.payAdmission();
        System.out.println("Sam has been admitted ... " + c4.admitted());
```